# Problem with multiple menus in theme

Tags: theme-development, menus, templates

I am having trouble trying to get my new theme working. I have all 4 menus working on my test server but when I move the theme to the live server and set up all but one (main-menu) will not show up.

Here is my code for the menus:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
'main-menu' => __( 'Main Menu', 'Bootstrap WP Primary' ),
'second-menu' => __( 'Second Menu' ),
'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' ),
'mobile-menu' => __( 'Mobile Menu', 'Mobile Menu' )
));
```

Here is the code from the current template:

```
register_nav_menus(
array(
  'main-nav' => __( 'Main Nav' ),
 ));
```

Is it a conflict with the main menu items?

[image: white Menu is Second Menu, Purple is Main]
[image: white Menu is Second Menu, Purple is Main and isn't showing up on live site]

Also upon inspection of the code the menu isn't even being populated on to the page.

Comment: Is the "Main Menu" the only menu item not showing up?  I am not clear on which menus are now not appearing on your live server?

Comment: Yes the main menu is the only one not showing. On the original theme I didn't have have all the additional menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a menu you need to use the `wp_nav_menu` function ([Codex reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)).

Try changing your template file to use the following code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: I tired that yesterday and it didn't work, oh well! Posting right!